# What does "book-length" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> I read every word of Judge Koh's book-length opinion, which portrays Qualcomm as a ruthless monopolist.

via: https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2019/05/how-qualcomm-shook-down-the-cell-phone-industry-for-almost-20-years/

I'd like to know what is the meaning of `book-length`?

Thanks,

Comment: book-length has only one meaning.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the journalist is describing the length of the judicial opinion written by Judge Lucy Koh.

Just to be clear, according to Wikipedia:

> A judicial opinion is a form of legal opinion written by a judge or a
>   judicial panel in the course of resolving a legal dispute, providing
>   the decision reached to resolve the dispute, and usually indicating
>   the facts which led to the dispute and an analysis of the law used to
>   arrive at the decision.

The Judicial Opinion written by Judge Koh was 233 pages long. The journalist is comparing it to a book, which is usually around 200 pages or longer.

Summary: "Book-length" is being used here to compare the length of Judge Koh's Judicial Opinion to that of a standard book.

Comment: Does that mean the content is so much?

Comment: In short, yes. It means it was very long.